# Saving PuTTY event log to a log file

Tags: putty, event-log

I am running options in putty for long hours and would like to find out if there is a possibility to have a continuous event log exported to either a .txt or a MS Word document.

Answer (score 1):

Use Plink (PuTTY command-line connection tool) instead of PuTTY, use the `-v` (show verbose messages) command-line switch and redirect both its standard and error output to a log file:

The Plink has the same command-line options as PuTTY.

```
plink.exe user@host -v > output.log 2>&1
```

See [Using the command-line connection tool Plink](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter7.html).

Answer (score 0):

This also an option in the settings of putty to output the log to a text file. You can chose to overwrite the file everytime you start a new session or just append to the end of text file.